# ошибка загрузки срипта Content Security Policy

Tags: node.js

нужна помощь в настройке политики. появилась такая ошибка:
Refused to load the script 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

````
  ```app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader(
    'Content-Security-Policy',
    ______________________//как правильно указать настройку? пробовал много вариантов
  );
  next();
});```
````

Это случилось после подключения helmet
так же не подгружались картинки с url, но эту проблему решил так

````
    ```app.use( helmet({
  contentSecurityPolicy: {
     directives: {
        ...helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives(),
        "img-src": ["'self'", "https:"],
     },
  },
 })
 )```
````

Comment: Вы подключили helmet, зачем вы хотите что-то выстявлять руками? Добавьте секцию по аналогии с картинками

Comment: ```app.use( helmet({
  contentSecurityPolicy: {
     directives: {
        ...helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives(),
            scriptSrc: ["'self'", "https://materializecss.com"]
 
     },
  },
 })
 )```ошибка:Error: Content-Security-Policy received a duplicate directive "script-src"..как правильно это сделать ?

Comment: `contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives()` устанавливает [дефолтное](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet-csp) значение директивы `script-src`, и потом вы добавляете ещё одно. Уберите `contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives()` и укажите нужные директивы явно.

Comment: точно такая же проблема, сейчас прохожу курс node js в.минина, после установки helmet сломалась верстка и не отображаются картинки. Вам как то удалось решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

````
```
app.use( helmet({
  contentSecurityPolicy: {
     directives: {
        ...helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives(),
        "img-src": ["'self'", "https:"],
        "script-src-elem": ["'self'", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js", "'unsafe-inline'" ] 
     },
  },
 })
 )
```
````